# “In cases where” vs. “If”

Tags: writing-style, ambiguity, conditionals

*[Garner's Modern English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ)* (2016), p. 147:

> H.W. Fowler wrote of *case*: "There is perhaps no single word so freely resorted to as a trouble-saver, and consequently responsible for so much flabby writing" (*FMEU1* at 65). Arthur Quiller-Couch condemned it is "jargon's dearest child." *On the Art of Writing* 106 (1916).
>
> The offending phrases include *in case* (better made *if*), *in cases in which* (usually verbose for *if*, *when*, *when*, or *whenever*), *in the case of* (usually best deleted or reduced to *in*), and *in every case* (better made *always*, if possible).

*Microsoft Manual of Style* (2012), p. 311:

> To avoid ambiguity, use *if* to express a condition; use *whether* to express uncertainty, and use *when* for situations requiring preparation or to denote the passage of time.

I have a technical paper with the following passage:

> #### Simple vs. associative arrays
>
> In cases where you need key–value pairs, use associative arrays; otherwise, use simple ones.
>
> ```
> // A simple array.
> Items = ["x", "y", "z"]
> ```
>
> ```
> // An associative array. x:10, y:15, and z:20 are key-value pairs.
> ItemPrices = ["x": 10, "y": 15, "z": 20]
> ```

Currently, I use *in cases where*; another possible option is *in cases in which*. Both versions seems to be very accurate, but quite wordy.

Possible shorter versions:

> a) If you need key-value pairs, use associative arrays; otherwise, use simple ones.

> b) If you need key-value pairs, use an associative array; otherwise, use a simple one.

Version B uses the singular form which I don't like.

Version A looks ambiguous to me. It lacks a point that *each* array can contain *many* key-value pairs.

My questions:

1. Is it correct that version A is ambiguous?
2. Is it a good case to use "old, dated, boring" replacement (*in cases where* or *in cases in which*) instead? Or there is a better way to fix this issue?

Comment: Related: ["Otherwise" after "where"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/538314/otherwise-after-where).

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, thanks. We are working on the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not think A was ambiguous, but I know the subject well enough to not notice.

I do, however, think you have a point and option B eliminates any possibility that a novice might misconstrue the wording in the way you foresee.

The case for *case* is really just opinion in most cases. *If* seems to be more clear in this case though, and simple phrasing "gets out of the way" of the real task of learning the material.